# NPM security not enforceable by running "npm config set ignore-scripts false"

Tags: node.js, npm

I have done some research that recommends `npm config set ignore-scripts false` to be run to avoid any possible malicious package from npm. However, after running the command,it seem to prevent `npm run...` commands from working in my node projects until I set it back to `false`. For example, I cant run node server and react client concurrently with **npm run dev** commands making development difficult. Is there a solution for this

Comment: It’s somewhat unclear exactly what your question/requirement is, however my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59028570/how-to-disallow-npm-packages-from-executing-post-install-scripts-without-disabl/59029692#59029692) demonstrates how to utilise the `--ignore-scripts` option when installing a package.

Comment: Hello @RobC, I have edited the question, I hope now it is clearer. Meanwhile Am checking with the link you have provided

Answer (score 4):

I think you missed something the idea is to ignore scripts installed via `npm install` *(there may be malicious publishers out there)* thus using `npm config set ignore-scripts true` will help to keep you safe, however there are projects where you want to use your own custom scripts.

You can use a local version of `.npmrc` to override said config, and manually change the value of `ignore-scripts` on your own, I would advice to setting to false when running `npm install` and setting it to true whenever you want to run your local scripts.

Remember that `.npmrc` will be located in the root of your project if you want to have it as local, and usually lies at `~/.npmrc` for global configuration.

For more information about `.npmrc` please check https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/npmrc.html

I hope this help you or any future folk out there!