# How to disallow npm packages from executing post install scripts, without disabling scripts defined in package.json?

Tags: npm

Watching a [nice YouTube video](https://youtu.be/24tQRwIRP_w?t=754) that mentions security concerns using the NPM package manager, I think it makes sense to disallow packages to execute code as they are installed. This NPM configuration will do that:

```
npm config set ignore-scripts true
```

But then scripts defined in `package.json` don't run. Including `npm start`. This is annoying.

Is there a way that I can prevent packages from executing code (I think it's the post install script if I remember correctly) and still allow scripts defined in `package.json` to run?

Just to be clear: I **DO** want to execute my own scripts. I **DON'T** want to execute 3rd party scripts during an `npm install`.

Comment: Pfft, why would you want to execute your own scripts? That's absurd... 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [npm-install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) documentation states:

> The `--ignore-scripts` argument will cause npm to not execute any scripts defined in the package.json.

So, essentially when you install a package you need to append the `--ignore-scripts` argument to prevent third-party packages from executing scripts, such as `postinstall`.

For instance:

```
npm install <pkg_name> --ignore-scripts
```

**Notes:**

- After installation of a third party package has completed you can still run your own npm scripts that are defined in *package.json*.
- > I think it makes sense to disallow packages to execute code as they are installed.

  That depends, when ignoring scripts using the `--ignore-scripts` argument you cannot always guarantee that the package you have installed will be fully functional - that depends on what tasks are carried out in the `postinstall` script for example.
- You cannot be specific about which scripts to ignore using the `--ignore-scripts` argument.

Comment: This seems like gaping functionality in NPM. surely I would want to be able to whitelist packages that are allowed to run scripts? For example, node-sass.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right, however your desired functionality doesn't exist in npm. So, did this not answer your question which was: _"I DO want to execute my own scripts. I DON'T want to execute 3rd party scripts during an npm install"_ ?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there's no way to ~~whitelist~~ opt-in to allow scripts only in selected packages.

But, seems like Yarn2 supports it now: https://dev.to/arcanis/introducing-yarn-2-4eh1#perpackage-build-configuration